# Does preloading an external SWF also preload external MP3s?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, flash, fla

I have an .swf file which loads several external MP3s, I want to make a preloader with an animated progress bar to ensure all of the Mp3s are loaded before the user can interact with the timeline. I have seen some people embed the MP3s in the flash file and then preload that .swf into another loader .swf.

I dont want to embed the MP3s, but would consider using a lader movie to load the main movie, will this method still work with external mp3s?

I have used AS3

Answer (score 0):

A loaded SWF will maintain it's AS3 code no matter if it's from the document class, on timeline or both.

If you have a Main SWF that loads an External SWF and External SWF is loading an MP3 file there is no problem with it what so ever.

Be careful with the loading security standards and the External SWFs loading sequence. Since it's a loaded SWF it will not have access to stage instantly (even in document class), in stead it will get it after it is added to stage (use ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener). It shouldn't be a problem if you're frame-scripting.

You might want to make a method in the External SWF that starts loading the MP3.